# How to make styles work for <col> tag?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a `col` tag within a table:

```
<!doctype html>
<table>
    <col style='color:red;background:blue;'/>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The style `background:blue` is getting applied, but not the style `color:red` (tested on IE, Safari, Opera, Chrome, FireFox).

What is the reason for that?

How do we apply a single text-color throughout a column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns). Only four properties apply to table columns and `color` isn't one of them.

This is a consequence of how the inheritance rules work in CSS.

It is explained [in more detail](http://ln.hixie.ch/?count=1&start=1070385285) by Ian Hixie.

If you want to apply foreground colours to a specific column, then you have to do it on a cell-by-cell basis. Unless you are complicating matters by mixing `th` and `td` on the same row, or using colspanning, you can do something like this:

```
td { color: blue; }
td + td { color: black; }
```

Comment: Thanks, the workaround seems to work. Btw, is there anyway to apply the workaround *inline*?

Comment: As well as `+ td`, you could use `td:nth-child`

Comment: @IMSoP, That works, great! But is there an *inline* version of it?

Comment: No. Anything done with a style attribute must be done on the element it is setting properties for.